# Compact subsets of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a nice characterization of the compact, connected subsets of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? If $K \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a compact, connected subset, can we say something about the support of all $f \in K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a characterization in Section 4.7(vi) of Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.  I don't have the time to retype it here, but roughly speaking, a set $K$ is compact iff it is bounded and functions in $K$ can be uniformly approximated by simple functions.

I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of "support".  Notice, for example, that if $f$ is any $L^2$ function whose support is all of $\mathbb{R}$ (such as $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}$), then the singleton $\{f\}$ is compact.

Comment: Is this essentially equivalent to the characterization given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet-Kolmogorov_theorem?

Comment: @mck: Actually they look rather different to me, but Bogachev cites the same paper of M. Riesz that's referenced in the Wikipedia page, so they may be equivalent or at least have common ancestry.